# Place of "not" in sentence

Tags: word-order, questions, negation, subject-verb-inversion

In *The Island of Doctor Moreau* they chant: "Are we not men?" So my question is: when we place *not* before *men*, not after *are*, what we are implementing?

Answer (score 1):

When *not* comes before *men*, it is merely being left in place.

> - We are not men.
> - Are we *_* not men?

In yes/no question formation, the verbs *be*, *have*, and the modal verbs are fronted (i.e. moved to the front of the sentence).  If none of these verbs is the inflected verb, we get [do-support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support), which works effectively the same way.

When the alternate form of *not* is used, namely the clitic/suffix *n't*, it does move to the front along with the verb, but this is because it is attached to the verb, so it must move along with it.

So, leaving the negation in place is the normal, default behavior for this kind of sentence, and a yes/no question where a free-standing *not* does move from its base position is the special case.

Comment: Did you mean something else in your first sentence, e.g., after the subject instead of after the copula? *Not* comes before *men* in both examples you give, as well as the OP's example.

Comment: I meant "before *men* " instead of "after".  Thanks.